# Pytorch: Image label

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, machine-learning, pytorch

I am working on an image classifier with 31 classes(Office dataset). There is one folder for each of the classes.  I have a python script written using PyTorch that loads the dataset using `datasets.ImageFolder` and assigns a label to each image and then trains. Here is my code snippet for loading data:

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import torch

def load_training(root_path, dir, batch_size, kwargs):
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.Resize([256, 256]),
         transforms.RandomCrop(224),
         transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
         transforms.ToTensor()])
    data = datasets.ImageFolder(root=root_path + dir, transform=transform)
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True, drop_last=True, **kwargs)
    return train_loader
```

The code takes each folder, assigns the same label to all images in that folder. Is there any way to find which label is assigned to which image/image folder?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The class ImageFolder has an attribute `class_to_idx` which is a dictionary mapping the name of the class to the index (label). So, you can access the classes with `data.classes` and for each class get the label with `data.class_to_idx`.

For reference: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/folder.py

Comment: It's a shame how this seems to not be mentioned in the docs at all.

Comment: FWIWF: class_to_idx returns labels:index, you need to swap keys and values to make them mappable to the index assigned to each image: {idx: label for label, idx in data.class_to_idx.items()}

Answer (score -2):

The ImageFolder class has an attribute "targets" that has the labels. The labels are associated with the name of the folders.

Comment: I don't know the torch version you're using, but  nowadays torch.dataset targets are associated with the index that created internally by the torch itself, not the folder name

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It might have happened because my folders were named numerically and I was new with imageFolder. So I thought its the labels as the Target contained same labels as i was expecting.